# Forbidden access after upload project on host

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, web-services, cpanel

I made my website by yii2 in **localhost** with xampp, that it works without promblem.

But now after **upload** my website on linux host I got bellow error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This is my htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Why this error occurred ?

Comment: change the permission in  yourapp/web server directory

Comment: @scaisEdge please explain more

Comment: check user permission on your directory  see this for a brief explanation  http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't have access to shell to write command like this.

Comment: My all files has 644 permission

Comment: just index.php has this error. others does not have

Comment: index.php is executed also .. not rw only but rwx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cpanel/WHM, you can change permission through the file manager. If it is still not working for you then delete the index.php and uploaded a new fresh one.

Also, check .htaccess in document root for any error.

Comment: yes I use cpanel. but I don't know what do I have to do

Comment: all of my php files is permission 644. you mean I have to change it?